# Capture argument value in Korn Shell

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a program that calls the shell script with argument values $1 $2 $3 $4. I have tried to capture it and put it in file so I can see the values, it can generate file but inside is empty. Where did I go wrong?

```
var= $1,$2,$3, $HOSE
echo "$var" > "value.txt"
```

Comment: No spaces allowed in shell around `=`

Comment: `var="$1,$2,$3, $HOSE"` -- the only legal spaces in an assignment are inside quotes, making them literal rather than syntactic.